# Jenkins git when repo is behind proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel, jenkins

I have the current situation: In my corporate network we have a jenkins machine and we need access to the repo of a vendor. We want to use ssh keys for authenticating to the repo.

The problem is that there is a proxy between us. Is there any jenkins plugin or configuration that would automatically create an  ssh over http proxy tunnel ?

Comment: A plugin will not solve that issue